# Django with Heroku: Getting started

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

So I have been reading up on Heroku's Dev Center, here on Stack Overflow, throughout the internet in general, and I have no idea how to get basically anything working on Heroku with my Django project.

My main issue is getting the Postgres database to work. I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` and it says it makes migrations and even creates a superuser, but when I get on to my deployed app I get the notorious "relation does not exist" error.

Reading around I see that you have to run `python manage.py migrate` on my local machine with my local database and then run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` or `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. I am confused as to if this is actually the case and if it is still the case for when I am using virtualenv.

**Edit**: Here is the relevant view which is throwing the "relation does not exist error" along with the corresponding models used.

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    route = models.ForeignKey('Route', null=True, blank=True)

    client = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, route: %s' % (self.name, self.route)


class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    client = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Route, Location


class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('pk', 'client', 'name')


class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location_set = LocationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ('pk', 'client', 'name', 'location_set')
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Location, Route
from .serializers import RouteSerializer, LocationSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class RouteList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        client = request.user.groups.all()[0]

        routes = Route.objects.filter(client=client)
        serializer = RouteSerializer(routes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Did you have a read of [the Django on heroku quickstart guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)?

Comment: Yes, I followed it to the letter initially, lead me to the "relation does not exist" error.

Comment: That error you're getting isn't because of a deployment issue. It's a problem with your models and/or your views. Please post the entire error, the relevant models and the view that throws the error.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the relevant code, but I am also wondering why my admin site is not including the models I registered via `admin.site.register(modelname)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not including migrations for your app models.
if you are using django 1.8 you can run following commands to generate migrations on your local,

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

add the migrations to git and deploy to heroku.
on heroku run the migration,

```
heroku run bash -a 'HEROKU_APP_NAME'
python manage.py migrate
```

you should not be using syncdb if you are using django>=1.7 as it is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) for django<1.7 use south migrations instead of django default.

Answer (score 0):

So figured this out for myself, problem was that I forgot to create an app via `startapp` and simply just put all my models, serializers, etc in the project directory. Once I created an app, moved everything into the app's folder, and adjusted all the imports and paths, everything was working fine.

Although I will also say, user peeyush113's advice was also relevant as syncdb wasn't really working so I had to used `makemigrations <app>` and then `migrate`.